# Efficient HIVE query for multi-level join

Tags: sql, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hql

I am converting a T-SQL UDF to HIVE HQL.  The UDF uses a recursive CTE to flatten a hierarchy in the source table by self-joining on a "parent" column.  To get rid of the recursion, I did multiple left joins to create the flattened hierarchy, i.e.:

```
select a.description, b.description, c.description, etc
from sourcetable a
left join sourcetable b on a.parent=b.id
left join sourcetable c on b.parent=c.id
etc.
```

The end result is that you have all of the levels of the hierarchy laid out by column, for example with familiar data:

```
Phoenix    Arizona       UnitedStates
WashDC     UnitedStates  NULL
Trenton    NewJersey     UnitedStates
```

Notice how the hierarchy can be "ragged."

There's no filtering in this use case, we're processing all records.

I have **TEN LEVELS** of hierarchy to deal with, and it runs fairly slow.  The original CTE ran in less than a minute, whereas the new query in hive takes about 9 minutes.  10-node cluster, 1.5M records, about 1.5GB data.  We only have mapreduce configured.

What is the best way to optimize for this use case?  I don't think partitioning would help because we're not filtering the data.  Would bucketing help?  Should I bucket on the record ID, or on the parent ID column?

Many thanks,
Richard

Comment: Hive, joins. Choose one! Seriously, you should stick to SQL Server (and use `CONNECT BY` queries, by the way).

Comment: Unfortunately, design constraints require that we move these UDF transformations over to hive and that's what creates this issue.  I suppose CONNECT BY would be appropriate moving to Oracle?  Not sure how that applies here.

Comment: How are left joins replacing recursion?  Wouldn't you want a bunch of unions?  As for performance, ugh.  How often does the data change? Can you store it flattened, and just refresh that once/day or whatever?

Comment: Its a data warehouse application, so yes, we process it once a day and store it flattened.  The reason for the recursion is the parent/child relationship in the records, promoting from one parent to the next until you get to the top.  Its common in data warehouse designs to flatten hierarchies for consumers/analysts of the data.  Also cubes don't perform well with parent/child hierarchies in a table, so flattening helps that a lot as well.  Could you describe how a union would work?  I'll modify my question and explain the requirement better.

Comment: Hive is not the right tool for that stuff, because *(a)* there is no easy way to distribute the graph traversal (or whatever term is appropriate); and *(b)* you have to make a strong assumption on the max depth of the tree, because SQL syntax requires it. Why don't you write a Java program to read the records from the original file (or connect to Hive via JDBC and `SELECT` them), push the parent/child relationships to a hash table, then iterate until the hash table contains all the branches (leaf -> all parents in order) -- it's just 1.5GB after all, much less for just the IDs